# random numbers from geometric distribution such that their sum equals SUM

Tags: python-3.x, random, distribution, stochastic

I want to draw k random numbers i_1,...,i_k  with min <= i <= max from an exponentially shaped distribution of values with m,std being median and standard of the population's values. The sum(i1,..,ik) should equal a given parameter SUM.

**Example:** 
*Given*:

k = 9 
 SUM = 175 
 min = 8 
 max = 40 
 m = 14

*Desired*:
[9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 17, 23, 30, 39]

I don't know if this is actually possible without depending on luck to draw a combination satisfying the SUM rule. I'd appreciate any kind of help or comment. Thank you.

EDIT: In a former version I wrote about exponentional distributions where an exact solution is impossible, rather I meant an exponentially shaped distribution with discrete values like a geometric distribution for instance.

EDIT2: Corrected the number k in the example.

Comment: Exponential distributions are continuous and not discrete so the probability of a sum of k of them hitting a given target is literally zero.

Comment: On top of problem, stated by @JohnColeman, exponential is unbound on the right end distribution (goes to infinity), but you require sampled numbers to be no more than `sum`. It's impossible as stated

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I updated the question a bit but I see your point. Is their way to generate a so shaped distribution with max and min values and then generate random sets where the SUM rule is satisfied?

Comment: I think that your example should have one more desired output (you list 9 values but say k = 10). Also -- does the fact that the numbers in your example are sorted have any significance. What are you trying to do? There is a vast literature on simulations in queuing theory that probably contains an answer for your question once you formulate the question clearly enough.

Comment: Thank your very much John. Part of the problem is that I cannot name the problem which would help me find some literature about it. Another way to think of the problem would be: Split a subset of natural numbers N = {1,..,n} (where n would have the value of SUM from above) into parts; where the lengths of the parts would resemble a geometric distribution. The parts should have length >= min and <=max and have median m. They should not be increasingly larger.